# statistical test for similarity

Tags: similarities

if you were comparing two randomly assigned groups of people for similarity at the start of a study, which statistical test would typically be best for:

1. Marital status
2. Height
3. Likert item statement - I like chocolate

Answer (score 0):

Marital status (assuming it is binary): usual choices are chi-squared or g-test

Height: t-test, assuming it is sufficiently Normal/bell-curved. If not Mann-Whitney

Likert: depends on the distribution. If you can bin it into 2 groups (e.g. "agree" and "strongly agree" vs everything else) then go with chi-squared, if you have many points on the scale and it's "sufficiently bell-shaped", you can get away with t-test. Otherwise you have to use something non-parametric, like Mann-Whitney.

Comment: None of those tests will demonstrate *similarity* ("similar" would be small effect size -- at least for certain kinds of effect size -- not large p-value).